# In AngularJS, from a controller, how do I add a value to a invalid input?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular, and working on my first full webapp with it.

I have a form with a field that is required.  So, I understand that it's bound ngModel value will be undefined.  The user can choose to enter the value in the field manually, or they can click a button triggering a function that will populate it.

By default the field is blank and invalid and I'm unable to set it's value from the controller.

In the view:

```
<input type="number" 
       min="0" 
       max="50" 
       placeholder="0" 
       name="entry-total-score" 
       id="entry-total-score" 
       ng-model="entry.total.score" 
       required />
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.entry.total.score = computedTotal;
```

How can I initialize that data binding manually?

Comment: $scope.entry.total.score = computedTotal; right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are simply forgetting to initialize total before trying to set score in your controller. It is also possible that (like Ben Diamant pointed out) that you are not setting your variable in your scope correctly.

The correct way to set it in the scope would be: `$scope.entry.total.score = computedTotal;`

You should be adding variables to the $scope or to "this" in the controller in order to access those variables in your angular HTML.

If you go the second route you need to make sure that you use the `ng-controller="<ControllerName> as <RefName>"` then use it in your HTML based on your ref name.

I made an example that I believe does what you want.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fbz1nSHPGZN2k4oYCCFA?p=preview

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I updated the question to match my code.  I was actually referring to the data value in the $scope.  In addition, when I init the value to zero in the controller ( $scope.entry.total.score = 0; ) I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined" js error.

Comment: In looking at your example code, I can see that I failed to initialize deeper into the nested JS object correctly.  "$scope.entry = {total:{}};" did it!  Thank you very much, I better understand now.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use jquery with angular, in your controller.

```
jQuery('#entry-total-score').val(computedTotal);
```

if you actually want the work and computedTotal is not a variable use .val("computedTotal")

If you want to only use angular then i think Ben's comments should work. It is nice to know though that angular and jquery play super nice. Instead of using the '$' for jquery just use jQuery and eveything works great. Also make sure to include jquery in your header with a

Comment: This is a bad way to do this. You should build your view (HTML) such that you don't need to select things based on an ID for a specific element. That is the BEST thing about angular. If you are doing it right you should have HTML that will respond to your model when you change data in the controller or services/factories. That way you never have to directly access elements though jQuery.
 There are a few special exceptions for that. One common one is when writing custom directives. That is a different case and even then it should be avoided if possible to get the most out of angular.

Comment: I totally agree, that is why i said bens comment would work, but if you end up using jquery plugins down the line it is a nice piece of knowledge to know you can always use jquery if needed.

Comment: Right, I just see a lot of new people to angular start using jQuery to fix their problems where there is a much better angular way to do it. In general when you are starting I think you should pretend jQuery isn't an option so you have to learn the right way of doing it. You are correct in saying the jQuery "normally" works well with Angular

Comment: I learned angular before jquery, but i recently needed to use a plugin for a project and was very surprised and happy to see how easily jquery integrated with angular since jquery already has so man plugins built for it.